# Flutter - Issue with using single Stream.asBroadcast() on multiple StreamBuilders

Tags: flutter

I have an app which has a single stream of data coming from firestore

```
static Stream<List<StudyGoal>> streamStudyGoals(
      {required String fromUserId}) {
    var ref = _database
        .collection(AppConfig.firestoreUsersIdentifier)
        .doc(fromUserId)
        .collection(AppConfig.firestoreStudyGoalsIdentifier);

    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.docs.map((doc) => StudyGoal.fromMap(data: doc.data())).toList());
  }
```

I have an "app database" which creates a new stream using the code above. Note that I am creating it as a broadcast stream

```
class AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase._privateConstructor();

  static final AppDatabase _instance = AppDatabase._privateConstructor();

  factory AppDatabase() {
    return _instance;
  }

  //Global
  final studyGoalsStream = FirestoreManager.streamStudyGoals(
          fromUserId: FirebaseAuthManager.getCurrentUser().uid)
      .asBroadcastStream();
}
```

Now I have 2 StreamBuilders on seperate pages that both use this same stream that is created above.

StreamBuilder #1

```
Widget buildStudyGoalsStream() => StreamBuilder<List<StudyGoal>>(
      stream: appDatabase.studyGoalsStream,
      builder: ...);
```

StreamBuilder #2

```
StreamBuilder<List<StudyGoal>>(
            stream: appDatabase.studyGoalsStream,
            builder: ...)
```

The undesired result I get is that the StreamBuilder which was built after the other gets stuck on ConnectionState.waiting (the one that gets built first works fine).
It appears that only one of these two StreamBuilders are able to use this stream correctly.

So, as a clarification

Produces undesired results:

```
StreamBuilder #1
    stream: appDatabase.studyGoalsStream,

StreamBuilder #1
    stream: appDatabase.studyGoalsStream,
```

Works perfectly (but creates two seperate streams):

```
StreamBuilder #1
        stream: FirestoreManager.streamStudyGoals(
          fromUserId: FirebaseAuthManager.getCurrentUser().uid),

    StreamBuilder #1
        stream: FirestoreManager.streamStudyGoals(
          fromUserId: FirebaseAuthManager.getCurrentUser().uid),
```

Any ideas???

Comment: it's because the broadcast stream not waiting for any of its subscribers. so the first one that builds first will get the data then the stream will not wait for the second one, try to produce the stream even after the second widget build. maybe you could update the data in the firebase console so the stream will produce a new stream and see your second Widget should show some data. I think

tip: try not to use Widget as functionlike you did `Widget buildStudyGoalsStream() => StreamBuilder<List<StudyGoal>>(
      stream: appDatabase.studyGoalsStream,
      builder: ...);`
not efficient.

Comment: Okay. Could you perhaps show some code of how I could solve this? There has to be a cleaner solution than having to update the firestore database every time I use the stream on a new Widget, right?

Comment: update the firestore that I mention up there was not for the solution just to prof the concept of what I'm saying. have you tried it? 
the better solution from my perspective is to make use of ValueNotifier .
in your init state listen to the stream and update the latest value in the ValueNotier value and all the widget that you want to use the stream value before is wrapped with the ValueListenableBuilder widget instead of StreamBuilder. this saves you expensive data-eaten app to only listen to one stream than multiple it saves user ntwk cst 
ValLisBld behavior is kind of the same as StrBld